# Append some text to a column while inserting an entry to a database

Tags: c#

```
var query = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0}({1}) SELECT '{2}',{3},{4},{5},'{6}' FROM {0} WHERE {7}='{8}'",xxxxxxx)
```

So I want value for `{4}` after retrieving from the database to be appended by `text="xyz"` in C# . But I am facing difficulty in appending as select would retrieve the data but can I append the `'xyz'` text in the query itself?

Comment: You're not retrieving any data in the code you've shown here. Provide a [mcve] in the question itself, with the code you're using to retrieve the data.

Comment: I think you need to read up on how to construct parameterized query's as well as how to insert data into a database table using C# and how to return data in C# when executing a Select Statement.

Comment: @vivek: thanks.. it helped

Answer (score 0):

You run separate query `SELECT '{4}' FROM {0} WHERE {7}='{8}'`, because in your query you are only inserting data not selecting.

You can also use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190315.aspx), to get last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. Use this id in youe select query where clause for faster result.